# Nifi Processor not preserving file extension

Tags: file, pdf, apache-nifi, mime-types, doc

I have a Nifi flow where a document file eg/pdf, doc etc is sent from a REST API to a Nifi ListenHTTP processor. The processor is configured to accept all headers. Here is my problem

Steps to reproduce:

1. hello-world.pdf sent to ListenHttp processor
2. inspect the queue and download the file

expected result:
The downloaded file should be named 'hello-world.pdf'

actual result: The downloaded file is named 'hello-world'

However, if I use a HandleHttpRequest processor followed by a HandleHttpResponse processor I get the expected result.

Does anybody know why the ListenHttp processor does not give me the expected result?

Comment: Your post does not match the question title - a file extention `.pdf` is not a mime-type, which would be `application/pdf`

Comment: @Sdairs Corrected!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to add an 'update attribute' processor with an attribute

key `mime.type` value `${Content-Type}`

This is because the HttpListener processor does not write this header by default.

Comment: So why not just use `Content-Type`?

Comment: The flow file already has Content-Type, it doesn't work. According to the documentation other HttpProcessors add mime.type automatically, HttpListener does not. Without the mime.type attribute the extension of the file in the flowfile payload will not be preserved.